# Question on the Riesz -Markov Representation Theorem with composition of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm taking an introductory measure theory course as an economics student and I've quickly found that I'm not as prepared as I should be for this level of course. I have little experience in proof based maths courses beyond introductory analysis.

I've been given the following homework problem that I'm really struggling with. My main problem is that I'm unsure what I'm required to do. Any advice / prod in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Can I ask that any explanations be as basic as possible. Many thanks for your help.

I can do question i) (after posting on here earlier) but I don't understand the other two. For question ii) I thought showing that $B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ then $\phi^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{M}$ is just the definition of $\mathcal{M}-\mathcal{B}(X)$ measurable map. As for the third I really have no idea.

$\textbf{Question}$

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $\mathcal{B}(X)$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on X. Also let $(M,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(M)<\infty$. Now let $\phi: M \rightarrow X$ be a $\mathcal{M}−\mathcal{B}(X)$-measurable
map and define $\Phi:C(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{equation} \Phi(f)=\int f \circ \phi \,d\mu\;\;\text{for all}\;\;f\in C(X) \end{equation}

i) Show that $\Phi$ is well defined. (i.e. show that if $f \in C(X)$ then $f \circ \phi$ is integrable with respect to $\mu$) and that $\Phi$ is a positive functional on C(X).

It follows from (i) and the Riesz Representation Theorem for positive functionals that there is a unique finite Borel measure $\mu_{\Phi}$ on $X$ such that \begin{equation} \Phi(f)=\int f  \,d\mu_{\Phi}\;\;\text{for all}\;\;f\in C(X) \end{equation}

Define $\mu_{\phi}:\mathcal{B}(X)\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ by $\mu_{\phi}(B)=\mu(\phi^{-1}(B))$ for $B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$.

ii) Show that $\mu_{\phi}$ is well-defined (i.e., show that if $B \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ then $\phi^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{M}$) and that $\mu_{\phi}$ is a Borel measure on $X$.

(iii) Show that $\mu_{\Phi}=\mu_{\phi}$.[Hint: Recall that if $f:M\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is a positive Borel function then there is an
increasing sequence $(s_n)_n$ of positive and simple Borel functions $s_n:M\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ such that $s_n \nearrow f$ pointwise.]

Comment: Question 2 depends on what your definition of a Borel measure is.  Some define a Borel measure to give compact sets finite measure.  Is that part of your definition?